# the values inside class not changing

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to change the values inside of class but its not changing
here my code
//html

```
<menu class="box">a</menu><menu class="box">b</menu><menu class="box">c</menu><menu class="box">d</menu>
```

//javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var after = ['html', 'css', 'js' , 'jquery']

for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].value = after[i];

}
```

Comment: you want to change the class name ?

Comment: You should use `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead of `value`.

Comment: nop .... i want to chage values inside class

Comment: box[i].innerHTML = after[i];

Answer (score 1):

To change the class name, use

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var after = ['html', 'css', 'js' , 'jquery']

for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].className = after[i];
}
```

From the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className)

Which would give you

```
<menu class="html">a</menu><menu class="css">b</menu>
<menu class="js">c</menu><menu class="jquery">d</menu>
```

To change the actual value of each element, you would use [innerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var after = ['html', 'css', 'js' , 'jquery']

for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].innerHTML = after[i];
}
```

Which would give you

```
<menu class="box">html</menu><menu class="box">css</menu>
<menu class="box">js</menu><menu class="box">jquery</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
var after = ['html', 'css', 'js', 'jquery'];
var j = 2;
for (i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {

  $('.box:nth-child(' + j + ')').html(after[i]);
  var j = j + 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<menu class="box">a</menu>
<menu class="box">b</menu>
<menu class="box">c</menu>
<menu class="box">d</menu>
```

try his

Comment: in this i just replace the html with array element what you want to know tell me he line of code

Comment: Ah, i don't need the explanation, But the  answer needs to be. If you answer has enough or simple explanation it would be helpful for the following readers.